# Two same size images does not render same

Tags: css, image, joomla, render

Is there any reason why two images that are same size would not render same. I'm using same module twice in Joomla, with two different images which are same in size and when rendered image in module 1 is 2px higher than second image

Comment: A link is worth a thousand words. :-)

Comment: localhost. height is calculated because images are downsized, but I don't understand why they are not re-sized at same height when they were same height to begin with

Comment: Templates, different module types, all sorts of things could explain why that would happen.  Need more info.